# Dagger in business logic and presenters

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger, clean-architecture

I'm already using Dagger2 and everything is working but I have a doubt about the proper way to integrate it into the business logic.
What Robert Martin says in "Clean Architecture" is that the DI frameworks, since they are frameworks, are details that should be kept away from the Entity and Use cases and more in general from all the classes that are at a higher level than the frameworks.

What R.M. suggests is to allow only the Main-module to know the DI framework used and to inject the other classes by yourself in such a way that you can replace one DI framework with another one without having to change the BL.

Is there a way to isolate Dagger in such a way that the business logic does not see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, yes: DI frameworks should also not be used in use case or entities circle. (That includes attributes and annotations)

The question would be how strict u want to handle this rule in ur project. Every rule and decision has pros and cons. As u said the pro of keeping DI out of the inner circles would be that u could easily replace it later. U would have to decide how big the benefit is compared to the cons, e.g.: having to pass dependencies to use cases manually.

Personally I currently try to handle it very strict in my projects. But my usecases tend to have only few dependencies ...